# SAS IFN function gets stuck

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Before we get to my question please note that I purposefully did not include example data in this post, as my problem occurs on my full dataset and subsets of it. I have two dataset with client data in the following format.

```
Have_1
+------------+------------+------+
|     dt     |   dt_next  |  id  |
+------------+------------+------+
| 30.09.2010 | 31.10.2010 | 0001 |
+------------+------------+------+
| 31.10.2010 | 30.11.2010 | 0001 |
+------------+------------+------+
| 30.11.2010 | 31.12.2010 | 0001 |
+------------+------------+------+
| 31.12.2010 | 31.01.2011 | 0001 |
+------------+------------+------+

Have_2
+------+-------+------------+------------+
| id   | event | start_date | end_date   |
+------+-------+------------+------------+
| 0001 | 1     | 31.10.2010 | 30.11.2010 |
+------+-------+------------+------------+
| 0001 | 2     | 31.10.2010 | 31.12.2010 |
+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I am trying to use the IFN function to put 1-0 flags in my dataset by using the following logic:

```
    Proc SQL;
    Create table want as
    Select a.*
          ,ifn(a.id in (select id from have_2 where a.dt <= end_date and start_date <= a.dt_next), 1, 0) as flg_1
          ,ifn(a.id in (select id from have_2 where a.dt <= end_date and start_date <= a.dt), 1, 0) as flg_2
    From have_1 as a;
    Quit;
```

The code works fine if I take only one client, however, if I take the full dataset (or even a small subset of it such as only 10 clients) then the code gets stuck in the sense that the process begins without error but simply never finishes. I tried setting indexes to both my input datasets, without success.
Are there any peculiarities to the IFN function, which can make it behave that way?

Comment: IFN() is doing nothing in this code, SAS already will evaluate a boolean expression as 1 (true) or 0 (false). Your issue is with the subqueries.  What are the two sub-queries trying to find?  Why the subquery instead of just a normal join?

Comment: The purpose of using this function is to make the code more concise. I used to do this calculation via joins, which required two PROC SQL statements. Why use two blocks of code if I can use just one, without losing too much in its readability?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to calculate.  Please explain in words what you are trying to  FLAG?

Comment: How many rows are in your tables ? For flags you don't need `ifn`, just use the logical evaluation which is already false~0 true~1. You appear to be checking for an existential condition, Instead of coding <value> `in` <select result-set> consider using `EXISTS` <select>.  EXISTS can be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why not just join and take the max of all events if any event's dates fall into those periods? That should eliminate the need to do two subqueries for every observation in HAVE1.

```
proc sql;
  create table want2 as
  select a.id
       , a.dt
       , a.dt_next
       , max(a.dt <= b.end_date and b.start_date <= a.dt_next) as flg1
       , max(a.dt <= b.end_date and b.start_date <= a.dt) as flg2
  from have1 a 
  left join have2 b
  on a.id = b.id
  group by 1,2,3
  ;
quit;
```

Note the issue is with the subqueries, not the IFN() function call.  Also there is no need for IFN() function here. SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 1 or 0.  So the expression `a=b` returns the same result as `IFN(a=b,1,0)` returns.

Comment: The code calculates the 1 year default flag and current default status for a client. In other words Flg1 indicates that an event in have_2 will happen in the next year from the current date in have_1. Flg2 indicates that the event has already started. The solution works for the given example thanks! However, what if my original table (have_1) has a bunch of other columns which I cannot include in the GROUP BY clause? If I use this code it will lead to duplicate value, which is why I was using IFN(), as I will need another block of code to clean the duplicates otherwise.

Comment: If you include columns that are neither keys or aggregates then SAS will re-merge aggregate values onto all of the detail rows.  For this problem Just add the DISTINCT keyword after SELECT keyword and the duplicate rows will be removed.